# Bulkify Aggregation Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, bulkification, aggregate

Is there a way to combine the two aggregates below.

```
public class AccountClass {
    public static void UpdatePartnerRollup(List<ID> AccID){
        // Get Opp Account
        Map<Id, Account> updates = new Map<Id, Account>();
        for(Id accountId: AccID) {
            updates.put(accountId, new Account(Id=accountId, First_Deal_Reg_Approved_Date__c= null, 
                                               Last_Deal_Reg_Approved_Date__c= null,
                                               First_Deal_Reg_Won_Date__c= null, Last_Deal_Reg_Won_Date__c= null));
        }
        for(AggregateResult dealApprovedDate: [SELECT AccountId Id, Min(Deal_Approved_Date__c) firstapproved, Max(Deal_Approved_Date__c) lastapproved
                                               FROM Opportunity 
                                               WHERE Direct_Sub_Partner__c  = :AccID GROUP BY AccountId]) {
                                                   updates.get((Id)dealApprovedDate.get('Id')).First_Deal_Reg_Approved_Date__c = (Date)dealApprovedDate.get('firstapproved');
                                                   updates.get((Id)dealApprovedDate.get('Id')).Last_Deal_Reg_Approved_Date__c = (Date)dealApprovedDate.get('lastapproved');
                                               }
        for(AggregateResult dealCloseDate: [SELECT AccountId Id, Min(CloseDate) firstwon, Max(CloseDate) lastwon    
                                            FROM Opportunity 
                                            WHERE Direct_Sub_Partner__c  = :AccID
                                            AND (StageName = 'Closed/Provisioning'
                                                 OR StageName= 'Closed Won'OR StageName= 'Provision')
                                            GROUP BY AccountId]){
                                                updates.get((Id)dealCloseDate.get('Id')).First_Deal_Reg_Approved_Date__c = (Date)dealCloseDate.get('firstwon');
                                                updates.get((Id)dealCloseDate.get('Id')).Last_Deal_Reg_Approved_Date__c = (Date)dealCloseDate.get('lastwon');
                                            }
        update updates.values();            
    }
```

Comment: You're trying to update four fields, right? You have a logic bug in your code...

Comment: Yes I'm trying to update the four account fields without running into governor limit. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but it requires slightly more code, may be much slower than your current code, and may actually run in to different limits (the 2000 aggregate result limit).

Basically, we have to now group by stage as well, and check each stage to see if it's a won state or not, and then update the fields appropriately.

Here's a rough draft of what that looks like:

```
public class AccountClass {
    public static void UpdatePartnerRollup(List<ID> AccID){
        // Get Opp Account
        Map<Id, Account> updates = new Map<Id, Account>();
        for(Id accountId: AccID) {
            updates.put(accountId, 
                new Account(
                    Id=accountId, 
                    First_Deal_Reg_Approved_Date__c= null, 
                    Last_Deal_Reg_Approved_Date__c= null,
                    First_Deal_Reg_Won_Date__c= null, 
                    Last_Deal_Reg_Won_Date__c= null
                )
            );
        }
        Map<Boolean, sObjectField> firstDateByWon = new Map<Boolean, sObjectField> {
            true => Account.First_Deal_Reg_Won_Date__c,
            false => Account.First_Deal_Reg_Approved_Date__c
        };
        Map<Boolean, sObjectField> lastDateByWon = new Map<Boolean, sObjectField> {
            true => Account.Last_Deal_Reg_Won_Date__c,
            false => Account.Last_Deal_Reg_Approved_Date__c
        };
        Set<String> closedStages = new Set<String> { 'Closed/Provisioning', 'Closed Won', 'Provision' };
        for(AggregateResult result: [SELECT StageName stage, AccountId Id, Min(Deal_Approved_Date__c) firstapproved, Max(Deal_Approved_Date__c) lastapproved, 
                                            Min(CloseDate) firstwon, Max(CloseDate) lastwon
                                    FROM Opportunity 
                                    WHERE Direct_Sub_Partner__c  = :AccID 
                                    GROUP BY AccountId, StageName]) {
            Account accountToUpdate = updates.get((Id)result.get('Id'));
            String stageName = (String)result.get('stage');
            Boolean isWon = closedStages.contains(stageName);
            Date firstDate = (Date)result.get(isWon?'firstwon':'firstapproved');
            Date lastDate = (Date)result.get(isWon?'lastwon':'lastapproved');
            sObjectField firstDateField = firstDateByWon.get(isWon);
            sObjectField lastDateField = lastDateByWon.get(isWon);
            Date firstAccountDate = (Date)accountToUpdate.get(firstDateField);
            Date lastAccountDate = (Date)accountToUpdate.get(lastDateField);
            if(firstAccountDate == null || firstAccountDate > firstDate) {
                accountToUpdate.put(firstDateField, firstDate);
            }
            if(lastAccountDate == null || lastAccountDate < lastDate) {
                accountToUpdate.put(lastDateField, lastDate);
            }
        }
        update updates.values();            
    }
}
```

Additional work may be necessary. For what it's worth, sometimes using an extra query is actually the correct way to go, and this is one of those times I'd argue that it's worth the effort, unless...

If the listed stages are IsWon, and you simply want to detect between IsWon and not IsWon, you can group by that field instead, which would result in:

```
public class AccountClass {
    public static void UpdatePartnerRollup(List<ID> AccID){
        // Get Opp Account
        Map<Id, Account> updates = new Map<Id, Account>();
        for(Id accountId: AccID) {
            updates.put(accountId, 
                new Account(
                    Id=accountId, 
                    First_Deal_Reg_Approved_Date__c= null, 
                    Last_Deal_Reg_Approved_Date__c= null,
                    First_Deal_Reg_Won_Date__c= null, 
                    Last_Deal_Reg_Won_Date__c= null
                )
            );
        }
        Map<Boolean, sObjectField> firstDateByWon = new Map<Boolean, sObjectField> {
            true => Account.First_Deal_Reg_Won_Date__c,
            false => Account.First_Deal_Reg_Approved_Date__c
        };
        Map<Boolean, sObjectField> lastDateByWon = new Map<Boolean, sObjectField> {
            true => Account.Last_Deal_Reg_Won_Date__c,
            false => Account.Last_Deal_Reg_Approved_Date__c
        };
        for(AggregateResult result: [SELECT IsWon isWon, AccountId Id, Min(Deal_Approved_Date__c) firstapproved, Max(Deal_Approved_Date__c) lastapproved, 
                                            Min(CloseDate) firstwon, Max(CloseDate) lastwon
                                    FROM Opportunity 
                                    WHERE Direct_Sub_Partner__c  = :AccID 
                                    GROUP BY AccountId, IsWon]) {
            Account accountToUpdate = updates.get((Id)result.get('Id'));
            String stageName = (String)result.get('stage');
            Boolean isWon = (Boolean)result.get('isWon');
            Date firstDate = (Date)result.get(isWon?'firstwon':'firstapproved');
            Date lastDate = (Date)result.get(isWon?'lastwon':'lastapproved');
            sObjectField firstDateField = firstDateByWon.get(isWon);
            sObjectField lastDateField = lastDateByWon.get(isWon);
            Date firstAccountDate = (Date)accountToUpdate.get(firstDateField);
            Date lastAccountDate = (Date)accountToUpdate.get(lastDateField);
            accountToUpdate.put(firstDateField, firstDate);
            accountToUpdate.put(lastDateField, lastDate);
        }
        update updates.values();            
    }
}
```

This looks nearly the same, but it will now query only two rows instead of N rows (where N is the number of opportunity stages you have per account).

Comment: You mentioned my code had a bug. What would you recommend?

Comment: @LauraBejjani It's fixed in this code. Your code assigned the *won* date to the *approval* date fields, so the won date fields would never be set, and the approval date would have been set to the won date if any opportunities were won.